# Symmetry in circuit

Tags: electric-circuits, symmetry, electrical-resistance

I have come across many circuits which have symmetry like up-down or left-right symmetry.(up-down/right-left symmetry)
[Generalized method for dealing with circuit involving symmetry?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/356645/)
I also got to know how equivalent resistance is to be measured in such cases. But to be honest even though I know the tricks I am feeling like a hollow sphere who does know how to deal with such situations but why were these situations caused are completely unknown to me. So I am looking for a bit of intuitive approach to such symmetrical circuits...why current or voltage in up-down/left-right symmetry are equal in the opposite sides of the axis we consider rather than being of different values.

It would be really appreciable and helpful if anyone could put up some intuitive approach for symmetrical circuits which won't be hard for a high school student to grasp.

Comment: Clarify what you mean by "up-down or right-left symmetry

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/356645/

Comment: OK. Then for a start, are you familiar with Delta-Wye transformations?

Comment: Also, put the link in your post so others won't ask the same question.

Comment: Yes I do know about delta-y transformation I mean how they ar converted/transformed but I have no idea about the derivation